# sub menu dissapear when too far down

Tags: submenu

i'm pretty new to css.

i'm trying to create a sub menu but while hover the main menu. But the whole sub menu keep dissapearing when i hover on second menu

this is my html

```
<ul id='drop-nav'>

 <li><a href='#'>Running Gear</a>
<ul>
  <li/>
  <li/>
  <li><a href='#'>Clothing</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Shoes</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Packs</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Electronics</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Accessories</a></li>
</ul>
```

and my css

```
<style type='text/css'>

ul {list-style: none;margin: 0px;
border-radius: 10px;}     
 ul li {display: block;position:relative;float: left;}
       li ul {display: none;}
 ul li a {display: block;text-decoration: none;
       white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;  }
 ul li a:hover {background: #F7AFB0;}
li:hover ul {display: block; position:absolute;}
  li:hover li {float: none;}
  li:hover a {background: #F7AFB0;}
  li:hover li a:hover {background: #7fceef;}
 #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}

li:not(:hover) li {display: none;}

</style>
```

any idea what's causing it?

Comment: Is the site live? If so posting the URL so we can have a look would be helpful

Comment: it's this one littlegoatgear.blogspot.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like this. Your HTML is not properly nested. Compare your code to mine and you should be able to see what you've done wrong.

You just need to style this code to suit your needs. The dropdown works correctly.

### CSS

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
ul li{
    float: left;
}
ul li a{
    display: block;
}
ul li ul{
    display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
```

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Running Gear</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Clothing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Packs</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: so i followed your code.It seems to fixed the dissapearing problem but the drop down menu doesn't show up as a list ( downward) but more like toward left

Comment: i got this to work somewhat. But now the drop down menu's pushing down the line underneath it.I'd like to have it sorta on top of it. Is it possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer in regards to your second question, seemed too long for a comment.

The reason for this is the border is on your main-menu class which grows when the dropdown is displayed.  I would say your best bet would be to give your top level menu items a class name like "top-menu" or something like that and add the border stylings to that .top-menu selector.  I think that should work.

Your other option would be to style the list items, this way the only border section that would move down would be the one where the actual dropdown menu is, the rest of the border would stay the same.  Not sure if that is what you want though.  Either way unless you absolutely position you "popular posts" sidebar then it will move down with your dropdown regardless of what you do with the nav border as your main-menu class is still growing.